# What is the relational antonym for the word mentioner?

Tags: single-word-requests, derivational-morphology, productive-affixes

Just like the relationship between employer and employee, what is the word for the receiving side of a mention?

An example of a sentence: The mentioner mentions the mentionnee, but mentionnee is not a word...

Another example is if we have two types of people, one is sending mentions they are the mentioners, the other are being mentioned, they are the mentionnees.

This is from I got the term "relational antonym" [What's the term describing employer-employee and similar role relations?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51774/whats-the-term-describing-employer-employee-and-similar-role-relations)

Comment: Can you give a situation and sentence where. this word might occur?

Comment: The mentioner mentions the mentionee @Mitch

Comment: Edit your question to give a full sentence with a real world situation. Do you want to be able to use the word in a sentence that does -not- also use the verb 'mention'. Note that though 'mentioner' is legally a word by English word formation rules, it is not a common thing to use - you just say 'X mentioned to Y' without specifying roles.

Comment: No I want to keep the mention verb so it will be self descriptive. @Mitch

Comment: The syntax of 'mention' is 'X mentioned Z to Y'.  In this relation X is the subject, Z is the object, and Y is the indirect object. So by this syntax the object is the other side of the relation. If you passivize such a sentence the subject becomes Z, the thing mentioned. If you came up with a scenario and sentence, it'll make it much easier for potential answerers to attempt an answer.

Comment: Mentioner and mentioned?

Comment: @StuartF what is the plural of mentioned? Also it's like employer and employed, it's not the same...

Comment: @Mitch I added sentences to the question. The real world scenario is a programming problem, I have a group of objects that are the mentioners and a group of objects that are mentionees and I have to explicitly name them with their part of the relationship.

Comment: @Mitch I'm afraid that's not right. *Mention* is monotransitive only, never ditransitive: there are no double-object constructions for it. In your example Y is the **object of the preposition *to***, which is an adjunct not an oblique argument let alone a core  argument. To be the indirect object it would have to be a different syntactic construct such as "X told Y Z" but it's not grammatical to *mention him something* in English. You seem to be confusing syntactic/grammatical roles like subject, direct object, and indirect object with thematic relations like agent, patient, and recipient.

Comment: @shinzou What evidence do you have that *mentionee* is “not a word”? I can't see any grammatical or semantic restriction that would forbid its productive creation here using standard derivational morphology. That's because deriving *-er/-ee* noun-pairs from transitive verbs is one of English's more productive suffix pairings.

Comment: @tchrist it's just not in any dictionary I was looking into, but I learned from your answer that English is like Hebrew and it's possible to create words that aren't explicitly in the dictionary :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is predicated upon a false assumption. It wrongly asserts that *mentionee* is not a word, but this is simply not true.

This is because deriving agent and patient nouns from transitive verbs using the *‑er* and *‑ee* suffices is productive in English. You can produce them *almost* at will whenever you need one.

That doesn't mean it is always guaranteed to be possible, but it usually is. Sometimes using an otherwise-productive affix can be blocked by particular grammatical, semantic, or lexical concerns. So for example although you can derive agent nouns like *talker* from nearly any verb, you cannot derive patient nouns like *talkee* because *talk* is intransitive so there can be no patient or beneficiary.

So go ahead and use *mentioner* and *mentionee*: after all, [everybody else does](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22mentionee%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en).